# Cannot Find Libraries [error: ld returned 1 exit status]

Tags: linker

As the title suggests, I am having a problem linking some libraries to my code. Minuit2 is in

```
/home/christian/root/include
```

and when I compile I run the following:

```
g++ -I/home/christian/root/include niminimzationExample.cpp -o niminimzationExample -L/Minuit2/lib -lMinuit2
```

which gives me the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lMinuit2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Being a newbie, I am not even sure what the error exactly means or how to fix it. I run Minuit2 on another machine, which the same command, and everything works fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

> I am not even sure what the error exactly means

The error means: linker searched for a file named `libMinuit2.so` and `libMinuit2.a` in `/Minuit2/lib/` and then standard directories (usually `/usr/lib` and `/lib`), and didn't find it anywhere.

> or how to fix it.

You need to find the directory in which one or both of `libMinuit2.{so,a}` are located, and then use `-L/that/directory` at link time to tell the linker where to find the library.